# Show that the stopped sequence is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

This is a series problem and I'm struggling with the last part.
I assume that the last part has nothing to do with previous ones, so i won't put up the other parts.
Question is :

> Let $\tau$ be a stopping time and $X=(X_n,{\cal F_n})$ be a martingale. Show that stopped sequence $X_{n}^{\tau}=( X_{\tau_{n}},{\cal F_n})$ where $\tau_{n}=\min\{\tau,n\}$ is a martingale.

I started with $E(X_{\tau_{n}}|F_{n-1})=E(X_{\min\{\tau,n\}}|F_{n-1})$
which then would have two cases, but all ends up with $E(X_{n-1})$, or should that be $E(X_{\tau_{n-1}})$?

Comment: Neither. The result should be $X_{\tau_{n-1}}$. // You could decompose the conditional expectation along the events $[\tau\leqslant n-1]$ and $[\tau\geqslant n]$ and compute the two terms separately and you might first try to show that $[\tau\geqslant n]$ belongs to $F_{n-1}$.

Comment: kkk: Any luck with these hints?